# React load in component onClick

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to load in a component when a button is clicked but when I click on the button () in the below code nothing appears to be happening. I'm just trying to display a copied message and then have it disappear shortly after it appears to show the user the selected text was copied to their clipboard.

This is my current code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Clipboard from 'react-clipboard.js';

const AddComponent = () => {
  console.log("copied")
  return (
    <p className="copied">copied to clipboard!</p>
  )
};

export default function Item(props) {

  const { itemImg, itemName } = props

  return (
    <>
      <Clipboard data-clipboard-text={itemName} onClick={AddComponent} className="item-container display-flex">
        <img src={itemImg} alt={itemName} className="item-img" />
        <h3>{itemName}</h3>
      </Clipboard>
      {AddComponent}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mostly you want to have a state control, to conditionally render the given component like `{ isTrue && <MyComponent /> }`. `&&` operator only evaluates `<MyComponent />` if `isTrue` has truthy value. `isTrue` is some state that you can control and change to display `MyComponent`.

in your case your onClick should be responsible to control the state value:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
export default function Item(props) {

  const { itemImg, itemName } = props
  const [isCopied, setIsCopied] = useState(false)

  const onCopy = () => {
    setIsCopied(true)
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsCopied(false)
    }, 600)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div data-clipboard-text={itemName} onClick={onCopy} className="item-container display-flex">
        <img src={itemImg} alt={itemName} className="item-img" />
        <h3>bua</h3>
      </div>
      {isCopied && <AddComponent/>} // short circuit to conditional render
    </>
  )
}
```

you could consider check the repo [react-toastify](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify) that implements Toast messages for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have `onClick` be a regular function instead of a functional component, and in the regular function implement some logic to update the state of `Item` to record that the Clipboard was clicked. Then in `Item`, instead of always including `<AddComponent />`, only include it based on the state of `Item`.